# Is it possible to filter/drop packets by MAC using nftables

Tags: linux, iptables, nftables

I have two systems that are connected over Ethernet and one system has a WiFi radio which provides internet access.

In this diagram sys#2 has the WiFi radio

```
sys#1  <---> Ethernet <---> sys#2 <---> wifi <---> internet
```

sys#2 routes packages from Ethernet (interface eth0) out to wifi (interface wlan0). sys#2 connects to an AP, sys#2 does not act as an AP itself. I'm looking for a way to use nftables or iptables to filter and drop packets on sys#2 which do not have a MAC matching sys#1. I'd be more interested in dropping packets arriving on Ethernet. What I'm trying to protect is to prevent someone from plugging into sys#2 and gaining accesses to the WiFi network.

Is this possible with nftables? I know someone could spoof their MAC to get around this but this is just a temporary measure until we can secure the connection with IPSEC or a VPN.

**Edit:**
Running the suggested nft command results in an error:

```
# nft add rule filter input iif eth0 ether saddr != A4:A3:A3:00:00:00 drop
<cmdline>:1:1-68: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
# ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
    inet 10.0.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255
     ...
```

Comment: if you use `nft`, you will have to create the chains in first place before you can add rules into them, eg. `nft add chain filter input {type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept; }`. If you don't already have nft already set up, it might be easier to use iptables instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **nft**, to drop all ethernet frames which are received from network interface `eth0` and do not have source address of `00:00:5e:00:53:00`:

```
nft add rule filter input iif eth0 ether saddr != 00:00:5e:00:53:00 drop
```

**iptables** allows similar filtering with [*mac* extension](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m mac ! --mac-source 00:00:5e:00:53:00 -j DROP
```

Comment: And you also have `ebtables` for MAC filtering: http://ebtables.netfilter.org/examples/basic.html#ex_anti-spoof

Comment: @PatrickMevzek [however it only seems to work on bridge interfaces](https://serverfault.com/a/205894/454263)